# Cache and Object serealization

Tags: caching, html, mootools, position

I have a question:
How can I save my div's position (I have 3 div (with class: my_box_position)) to the cache and restore again using Mootools:
My code:

```
Element.implement({
serializePos: function(){
        var coors = this.getCoordinates();
        return {                
                id: this.id.replace('rb_',''), 
                lefty: coors.top.toInt(),
                leftx: coors.left.toInt(),
                righty: coors.height.toInt() + coors.top.toInt(),
                rightx: coors.width.toInt() + coors.left.toInt(),
                minimized: this.hasClass('rb_minimized')
            }.toSource();
        }
})
```

Used like this:

```
var obj = $$('.my_box_position').serializePos();
Cookie.write('box_position',obj);
```

Now we read from cookie:

```
if (typeOf(Cookie.read('box_position')) != 'null') {    
                var boxes = eval(Cookie.read('box_position'));
                ...??? How can I set my div position here? 
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: was this your plugin: http://mootools.net/forge/p/element_serializearea

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`setStyles`](http://www.mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Style#Element%3asetStyles)** to set height, width and left and top position (using a correct `position` such as `absolute` or `relative`, depending on your case).